# jquery validation invalidHandler

Tags: jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation for my form and i have set an  invalidHandler that show an error on the top of form and scroll to that message.

I am trying to hide that message when field validation is success but i can not find anything in validate() option that will help me.

(**not when user click submit**.For example if i have one textbox on the form and click submit i display the message, when the user write something to textbox and it pass the validation i want to hide the message without the user click submit)

Maybe i can count the number of errors on success but i dont know how.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you give your error at the top of your form an id of 'foo',

```
<div id="foo">error here</div>
```

and set the **errorContainer** option, then when the form is valid again the element #foo will disappear

```
$("#myform").validate(
 { 
  errorContainer: "#foo"
 }
});
```

note the element #foo must be within the form

Comment: Thanks, its working.Is is possible to replace the error with a success message instead?